# Local minimizer

Tags: optimization

Given the feasible set, the point, and the gradient (and in some cases also the Hessian), how do you determine if the given point is definitely a local minimizer? Do you use the first-order necessary condition, and/or the second-order necessary condition and/or the second-order sufficient condition? If yes, then how do you determine the feasible direction? If no, how do you solve it?
Thanks

Comment: You would need to use sufficient conditions, which usually involve the Hessian being positive definite. If you are at a local minimum, there is no (local) feasible direction.

Comment: Do I also need to check the necessary conditions?

Comment: Here is an example:
f: R2 -> R, Feasible set is {x =[x1,x2]T : x1 >=1}, Point is [1,2]T and gradient is [1,1]T

Comment: Then $f$ doesn't have a local minimum at $(1,2)^T$, since the direction $(0,-1)^T$ is a descent direction (since $\langle \nabla f ((1,2)^T), (0,-1)^T \rangle = -1 <0$).

Comment: How do you pick the direction (0,-1)T? Do you just try different values?

Comment: Any direction $h$ that has $\langle \nabla f ((1,2)^T), h \rangle <0$ is a descent, the direction I picked is the projection of $-\nabla f ((1,2)^T)$ onto the constraint set (which is a nice set as constraint sets go).

Comment: Ok. However isn't ⟨∇f((1,2)T),(0,−1)T⟩ = -2 (still negative) or am I mis-understanding the notation?

Comment: Also, if you keep trying different directions how do you know when you are done (which will imply that it is a local minimizer)? Or is there a test that you can do to check this?

Comment: Hmm, there is a vast body of literature dealing with the subject of optimization algorithms. In the example you gave you could search for 'gradient projection' (since the constraint set you gave is 'nice').

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it.